# Slim.php is missing from Slim-3.x

Tags: php, mysql, rest

I am following a tutorial from here:

https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/php-restful-api-framework-slim-tutorial-1/

The tutor said download slim at:

https://github.com/slimphp/Slim

Everything seems ok now but when I try to load the REST at Mozilla's REST easy app. I was given the error:

> Warning: require(.././libs/Slim/Slim.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\StudentApp\v1\index.php on line 5
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '.././libs/Slim/Slim.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\StudentApp\v1\index.php on line 5

I checked the Slim directory and Slim.php is really missing. Can anyone pls help me. Thanks.

Comment: Could you put the relevant sections of the tutorial in the answer so folk can read at a glance?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of Slim.php and `\Slim\Slim()`, just use App.php and `\Slim\App()` as mentioned in [the documentation of Slim](https://github.com/codeguy/Slim).

**To Explain Well**

Use:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

Instead of:

```
require '.././libs/Slim/Slim.php';
```

And use:

```
$app = new \Slim\App();
```

Instead of:

```
$app = new \Slim\Slim();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution. What I did is that I downloaded the Slim-2x version from here:

https://github.com/codeguy/Slim

I copied the Slim.php of the Slim-2x to the Slim-3x. It worked but I think there are better solution for this.